# Can a project go to production with non-release versions of dependencies?

Tags: spring, maven, dependency-management, maven-dependency

I would like to know the difference between RELEASE, SNAPH, and just version number

So, I am working on a project, in which I have to change spring-core dependency version from 5.2.9.RELEASE to 5.3.11

In my maven repository, under org->springframwork->spring-core, I see below

5.2.8.RELEASE
5.2.9.RELEASE
5.3.4
5.3.6
5.3.8
5.3.9
5.3.10
5.3.11

My project builds successfully only with the 5.3.11 version of spring-core. It is ok to release my project to production with non-release version of spring-core?

Comment: This is a special version scheme of the spring framework.

Comment: Don't just change spring-core you need to change all spring related dependencies, only upgrading part of spring will lead to issues. Spring dropped the **RELEASE** part as of Spring 5.3 so 5.3.11 is as much a RELEASE version as 5.2.9.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Team changed the version scheme of some projects back in April 2020. As documented in [this blog](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/30/updates-to-spring-versions) from the Spring Team.

So in short the 5.3.x line doesn't have the **RELEASE** suffix anymore for the final versions, as it was removed.

When upgrading a framework make sure you upgrade all parts of the framework. Not only upgrade `spring-core` but also all other related Spring Framework modules to the same version, if not this will eventually come back to hunt you with weird issues (memory, performance, transactions, missing methods etc. etc.).